# Multi-user touch screen, multi-touch capability

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, multi-touch

I have a grid with two column, in this sample I have web browser in each column, if I touch left columns and want to touch element in right or zoom both element, it is not possible. How can I make touches independent. How to slipt monitor into two surfaces?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WebBrowser Grid.Column="0" Source="http://www.google.com/"></WebBrowser>
    <WebBrowser Grid.Column="1" Source="http://www.Stackoverflow.com/"></WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```